# Videoview re-buffer on Scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I am implementing the `VideoView` inside the `Recyclerview`. On Scrolling the  `VideoView` re-buffer again until it is not started, when it starts plays,the its fine on little scrolling. Because of this,  `VideoView` takes lot of time to start.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                         int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                //get the recyclerview position which is completely visible and first
                int positionView = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                Log.i("VISISBLE", positionView + "");
                if (positionView >= 0) {
                    if (oldFocusedLayout != null) {
                        //Stop the previous video playback after new scroll
                        CustomVideoView vv_dashboard = (CustomVideoView) oldFocusedLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
                        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) oldFocusedLayout.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                        vv_dashboard.stopPlayback();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    currentFocusedLayout = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findViewByPosition(positionView);
                    CustomVideoView vv_dashboard = (CustomVideoView) currentFocusedLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
                    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) currentFocusedLayout.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                    //to play video of selected recylerview, videosData is an array-list which is send to recyclerview adapter to fill the view. Here we getting that specific video which is displayed through recyclerview.
                    playVideo(urls.get(positionView), vv_dashboard, progressBar);
                    oldFocusedLayout = currentFocusedLayout;
                }
            }

        }

    });


 private void playVideo(Video video, final CustomVideoView emVideo, final ProgressBar buffering) {
    emVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video.getUrl()));
    buffering.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    emVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
            buffering.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What you want to achieve? You have one VideoView and want to change video whenever user scrolls to another item on list?

Comment: @SebastianŚwierczek No, it is `Recyclerview` with multiple videos. On getting full focus it autoplays, problem is that when video is loading,on little scrolling like just touch, it start loading again, which makes video delay in playing.

Comment: you should store the duration(till the video has been played,default is 0) of the `videoView` if once the video is buffered  and played ( mind the duration) and next time this position is comes onFocus pass the duration to media player.

Comment: @ShikhaRatra as far as i understand you need to combine multiple methods from `VideoView`. You can check if video is playing, when it lost its focus then just pause it. When item is focused again, `VideoView` was not destroyed and is in paused state just resume it. In case when `VideoView` was destroyed you have to seek to last saved position after it is prepared. I think you should also implement some delay before preparing video to avoid multiple unnecessary prepares during fast scroll (for example use `Handler`).